# Prevent swing animation from jumping

Tags: java, swing

I've made this basic example, using a `JPanel` and a `javax.swing.Timer` and I would expect the animation to be relatively smooth.

If I keep the mouse moving over the window, the animation is smooth. If I don't interact with the window at all, then the animation starts to jump.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SmoothSwing{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double theta = 0;

    public void step(){
        x = 175 + 175*Math.sin( theta );
        y = 175 + 175*Math.cos( theta );
        theta += 0.02;
        if(theta > 6.28) theta = 0;
    }

    public void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("smooth");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 400);
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawOval((int)x, (int)y, 50, 50);
            }
            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
                return dim;
            }
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return dim;
            }
        };
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Timer timer = new Timer(30, evt->{
            step();
            panel.repaint();
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new SmoothSwing()::buildGui );
    }

}
```

What it looked like to me was that the repaint's are accumulating and getting repainted in clumps. So I commented out the line `super.paintComponent(g);` which would cause the panel to not get cleared.

[image: Screen without clearing circles]

When I do that, I can see that paintComponent is getting run because all of the circles are being drawn, but the display is still only updating after multiple circles have been drawn.

I have this issue on jdk-14+36, jdk-11.0.6 and 1.8.0_181 using Linux. Ubuntu 18.04.

Here are graphics comparing the difference. I had trouble controlling the speed of the gifs, but this illustrates what is happening.

[image: Expected behavior.]
[image: After short inactivity.]
[image: After a bit longer.]

Left to right, if I move the mouse over the window I get the behavior on the left, after I stop it gets a bit jumpy (middle) then it gets more jumpy (right).

One thing I can do to avoid the problem is to split my timer into two tasks.

```
Timer t1 = new Timer(30, evt->step());
Timer t2 = new Timer(3, evt->panel.repaint());
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: What happens if you do all the calculations in advance and store the results in an ArrayList, perhaps an `ArrayList<Point2D>`,, and then simply iterate through the list (or lists) in your Timer?

Comment: Is this any smoother ? `Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g; 
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 50, 50));`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried making a list of points, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @c0der I am surprised that the rendering hints have any affect on the frame rate, but when I use the rendering hints it only slows down 1 level of slowdown.

Comment: The `javax.swing.Timer` by default coalesces events. I am thinking maybe you get this behavior because of coalescing of events. If so, make sure to call `setCoalesce(false)` on the timer and retry. Either way, I can still not reproduce the error. I just hint you to try `setCoalesce(false)` (or even `true`). The jumping may become more apparent for smaller delays.

Comment: @gthanop I gave it a shot, and didn't see any difference. I am thinking this is an os issue. I think the timer and the repaint are happening fine, but the os/window isn't updating the display. I could see how this and coalescence would look the same, but if I fire off repaint calls at 1ms the app keeps up.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve smoother animation by:
- Using finer theta step
- Update in higher frequency 
- Use double values to paint:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SmoothSwing{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double theta = 0;

    public void step(){
        x = 175 + 175*Math.sin( theta );
        y = 175 + 175*Math.cos( theta );
        theta += 0.002; //finer theta step
        if(theta > 6.28) {
            theta = 0;
        }
    }

    public void buildGui(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("smooth");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 400);
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 50, 50));
            }
            @Override
            public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
                return dim;
            }
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return dim;
            }
        };
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Timer timer = new Timer(3, evt->{ //higher frequency update
            step();
            panel.repaint();
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new SmoothSwing()::buildGui );
    }   
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't that theta is too fine, the animation is drawn in chunks. It starts out fine but once there is no input the frame rate slows down and the circle moves larger steps. Then after waiting a little longer it slows down even more and it takes larger steps. If I move the mouse over the window, the animation keeps going in the expected manner.

Comment: Did you try the code I posted ? It is way smoother than the original one.

Comment: The issue I have with this solution is that, it is increasing the overall frame rate. Currently I set the frame rate to ~30hz, your solution cranks it up to ~300hz. I am surprised that it solves the movement in chunks issue, but why can't I set the framerate to be 30hz? Why does it eventually start going slow. According to this answer, I should run my animation at a rate I like, but just swamp swing with repaints.

Comment: It is not the 300Hz which does it but the finer theta. You can expect coarse steps and smooth movement.

Comment: Another question though, do you see the delay I am talking about? If you run the example as I provided and leave the window alone for a second or so, does the animation get choppy?

Comment: No sorry. I can't see that. Also I don't see that mouse hoover has an effect. I can see that the circle moves in little jumps when both x and y change. The motion is smoother when x is close to 0 (circle is at the top or at the bottom) and when y is close to 0 (left and right).

Answer (score 1):

When I run either you example or cOder's example I don't notice any change in motion over time. It remains constant as best as I can tell.

> What it looked like to me was that the repaint's are accumulating and getting repainted in clumps.

The only way I now to bypass the `RepaintManager` in Swing is to use the `paintImmediately(…)` method. This causes the component to be painted right away without being added to the end of the EDT. It is not recommended to be used because it can decrease overall painting performance.

Any methods that updates the state of your class should be part of the class, not external to the class. So, I modified you original code. This allows me to play with the painting logic in the step() method:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SmoothSwing2 extends JPanel
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double theta = 0;

    Dimension dim = new Dimension(400, 400);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 50, 50));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        return dim;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return dim;
    }

    public void step()
    {
        x = 175 + 175*Math.sin( theta );
        y = 175 + 175*Math.cos( theta );
        theta += 0.008; //finer theta step
        if(theta > 6.28) {
            theta = 0;
        }

        repaint();
//      paintImmediately( getBounds() ); // repaints the entire panel
//      paintImmediately(x - 5, y - 5, 60, 60); // repaint only the circle

    }

    public void buildGui()
    {
        SmoothSwing panel = new SmoothSwing();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("smooth");
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Timer timer = new Timer(3, evt-> panel.step)
        timer.start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new SmoothSwing2()::buildGui );
    }
}
```

I don't notice any difference using either of the 3 approaches.

If you continue to notice repaints be "accumulated", then maybe is your OS that is not giving the application CPU constantly?

I use JDK 11, on Windows 10.

Comment: I believe it can be the OS too. Since the image produced without calling `super.paintComponent` has all of the circles drawn, I suspect repaint is causing a paintComponent to fire at the required rate, but the os just isn't displaying the updated graphics. It's very systematic for me though. I stop moving the pointer , a little time later the frame rate drops.