# Small lags when using swing for a game

Tags: java, kotlin, swing

I have the following code snippet :

```
import java.awt.*
import java.util.Date
import javax.swing.*
import kotlin.math.*

fun now() = Date().time.toDouble()


class GameWindow: JFrame() {
    private val game = GamePanel()

    init {
        defaultCloseOperation = WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE

        isResizable = false
        isVisible = true

        add(this.game)
        pack()
        setLocationRelativeTo(null)
    }

    fun startGame() {
        this.game.start()
    }
}


class GamePanel: JPanel(), Runnable {
    private val mainThread = Thread(null, this, "GameThread")
    private var firstRendering: Double? = null

    init {
        preferredSize = Dimension(1200, 800)
        background = Color.BLUE
        isDoubleBuffered = true
    }

    fun start() {
        mainThread.start()
    }

    private fun setup() {
        firstRendering = now()
    }

    override fun run() {
        setup()
        while (true) {
            updateState()
            repaint()
        }
    }

    private fun updateState() {
        // TODO
    }

    override fun paintComponent(g: Graphics?) {
        super.paintComponent(g)
        val g2D = g as Graphics2D

        g2D.scale(0.5, 0.5)

        // A square that describes a spiral
        if (firstRendering != null) {
            val t = (now() - firstRendering!!).toInt() / 10
            g2D.color = Color.BLACK
            g2D.fillRect(
                1200 + (t * sin(t.toDouble() * PI / 720) / 5).toInt(),
                800 + (t * cos(t.toDouble() * PI / 720) / 5).toInt(),
                200,
                200
            )
        }

        g2D.dispose()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val window = GameWindow()
    window.startGame()
}
```

When I run this, everything works as intented (I get a window with a blue background and a square moving), except for the fact that the square's movement seems somewhat jerky. It isn't that visible (the square doesn't stop and then jump a few pixels), but I have the impression that the movement isn't fluid. I'm not running anything else beside this for now, and I fear the problem might get worse when more things are added.
It's more visible when the square's moving slow. I also have a PC that's good enough to make it run smoothly, especially with so little graphics, so I don't know where this is coming from. I am working under Windows 10.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for reading !

PS : I'm somewhat of a maniac. Don't worry if the lag doesn't catch your eye at first, but once I've seen it I couldn't stop thinking about it (and also because in my opinion something so simple should run perfectly smooth)

Comment: I'm not sure it's responsible for the issue you observed, but it certain is *an* issue that you're trying to drive the application from your own thread.  A Swing GUI should be driven from the AWT event dispatch thread.  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` can help other threads push work onto the EDT, but it's best to limit the need for those.  Use Swing timers to schedule periodic tasks such as for running an animation loop.  Use appropriate callbacks for responding to user input.

Comment: Also, do not `dispose()` the `Graphics2D` passed into your `paintComponent()` method.  You are not responsible for that object's lifecycle, and Swing might not be done with it.  Dispose only of those you create yourself (via `Graphics.create()`).

Comment: I did what you said, but it made things worse. I'm keeping the changes (because what you said totally makes sense), but the issue's not solved.

Comment: Probably related: [Prevent swing animation from jumping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61188644/2402272)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce a distinct jerkiness in a Java version of your animation.  At first I thought it was a result of repaint requests being coalesced, which is a known and intentional mechanism by which Swing can shed work when stressed. But that shouldn't happen if the event-dispatch thread is not stressed, and it clearly wasn't.

I eventually discovered that I could resolve the issue by invoking `getToolkit().sync()` to the end of `paintComponent()`.  This tells me that, at least in my case, the issue was not that the panel was not being repainted by Swing, but that multiple repaints were being performed between updates of the native peer.  And that also explains why I found that waving the mouse pointer over the window relieved the jerkiness: Swing knew it had to update the peer to paint the portion revealed by moving the mouse pointer.

In addition, I pushed all the GUI work into the EDT, where it needs to be, and made some other minor adjustments.  This is my final result (in Java, not the equivalent Kotlin):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.lang.Math.cos;
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
import static java.lang.Math.sin;

public class GraphicsDemo {

    final static int TICK_DELAY = 10;

    static class DemoPanel extends JPanel {

        private Optional<Instant> startInstant = Optional.empty();

        public DemoPanel() {
            super(true);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 800));
            setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        }

        void updateState() {
            // ...
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Instant now = Instant.now();

            if (!startInstant.isPresent()) {
                startInstant = Optional.of(now);
            }
            double centisElapsed
                    = Duration.between(startInstant.get(), now).toMillis() / 10.0;

            int x = 1200 + (int) (centisElapsed * sin(centisElapsed * PI / 720) / 5);
            int y =  800 + (int) (centisElapsed * cos(centisElapsed * PI / 720) / 5);

            // Copy the Graphics object because we're going to persistently modify it
            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2D.scale(0.5, 0.5);
            g2D.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2D.fillRect(x, y, 200, 200);
            g2D.dispose();

            // This was important:
            getToolkit().sync();
        }
    }

    // This method should be run on the EDT
    public static void startGUI() {
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame("GraphicsDemo");

        DemoPanel panel = new DemoPanel();
        // javax.swing.Timer: fires events on the EDT
        Timer animationTimer = new Timer(TICK_DELAY, ae -> panel.updateState());

        mainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainWindow.setResizable(false);
        mainWindow.add(panel);
        mainWindow.pack();

        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
        animationTimer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(GraphicsDemo::startGUI);
    }
}
```